# graph API - facebook og image tags set but still rendering wrong image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have set my meta tags for using the sharer API as below but Facebook is picking up the wrong image and description

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/tips-and-motivation/content/week-1-media-2" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/assets/tips-and-motivation/week-1-assets/Monument-5.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="900" /> 
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="540" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="test" />
```

All looks to be set right as per the documentation i've read online but every time I perform a new scrape it picks up a different image and the description is also not set... Here are the error messages the sharer is returning:

> Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided,
>   even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property The 'og:title' property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property The 'og:description' property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
>   provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Share App ID Missing  The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly
>   provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will
>   be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in
>   url when open the share dialog.

Comment: What is the URL that you are trying to share?

Comment: unable to share that im afraid

Comment: Then we are unable to help you

Comment: Not even a clue as to where to start looking?

Comment: The problem is that you are not returning og:image when Facebook scrape your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WizKid said we really need to see the URL to help diagnose.  But if that's not possible, here's where to start:

1. If you use any kind of caching on your site, try clearing it and then...
2. Testing your link in the FB Sharing Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/